# Do Web Audio API events run in a separate thread?

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

I'm particularly interested in the ***onaudioprocess*** of the ***ScriptProcessorNode*** (until recently called *JavaScriptNode*). It is an event listener which is called periodically for audio processing. Does it run in a separate thread?

I'd want to feed the data to a circular buffer and process it outside of this callback so I don't hog the CPU. I can use web workers for the async processing, but AFAIK I'd need a different implementation of the ring buffer in the case of different threads.

Is there a way to test this?

Comment: are you also streaming the audio using web sockets ?  How did you get on ?  ... on side node would be nice to launch Web Audio from inside a Web Worker thread !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All JavaScript is single-threaded, synchronously executed. Any asynchronous stuff is done via events, which add their handlers to the task queue - to be executed when the current task is finished.

To use separate threads, you would need an environment like WebWorkers - every thread has its own execution context (global scope) and task queue; communication between them is done via events.

As the `onaudioprocess` handler seems to live in the same scope as the DOM, it is quite unlikely that it runs in its own thread. If you really have a computationally intensive task that makes your page unresponsive, you should use a WebWorker into which you feed the audio events:

```
myScriptProcessorNode.onaudioprocess = myWebWorker.postMessage;
```

Comment: I have used web workers before. If the onaudioprocess is being executed in the main thread, then I guess I wouldn't need a locking ring buffer, just a simple synchronous one, right? I'll rephrase my question a bit.

Comment: Yes, with JavaScript you never need locking - there is only one executed task at a time.

Answer (score 1):

With Bergi's solution, you're going to run into issues with the [structured clone algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm) not being able to copy read only parameters in the audioProcessingEvent. What you need to do is break out the parts you need from the event that are cloneable, and pass them over to your worker in a different data structure like so:

```
_onAudioProcess(audioProcessingEvent) {
  const {inputBuffer, outputBuffer} = audioProcessingEvent;
  // The output buffer contains the samples that will be modified and
  // eventually played, so we need to keep a reference to it.
  this._outputBuffer = outputBuffer;
  const numChannels = inputBuffer.numberOfChannels;

  const inputChannels =
    Array.from({length: numChannels}, (i) => {
      return inputBuffer.getChannelData(i);
    });

  this._worker.postMessage({
    command: 'DO_STUFF',
    inputChannels: inputChannels,
  });
}
```

You're also going to need to access the reference to your outputBuffer in setMessageHandler, in order to copy the processed data back to be eventually played by the user.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it seems like not even WebAudio's normal nodes run in a separate (non-UI) thread, as there's heavy crackling etc. when there is heavy UI (DOM, CSS, etc.) updates.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript called from a `ScriptProcessorNode`'s event listener is run in the main thread. **Use [Audio Worklets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Using_AudioWorklet) to run in a separate thread.**

As of 2024, `ScriptProcessorNode` has been [deprecated](https://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#ScriptProcessorNode), and developers are encouraged to use Audio Worklets.

For completeness, Web Audio API [mandates](https://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#control-thread-and-rendering-thread) that processing be split between 3 threads:

- the "control" thread, which is your Javascript engine main thread
- "decoding" threads, for demuxing, codec decompression, resampling, etc
- the "rendering" thread, for processing AudioNodes/AudioWorklets and communicating w/ the operating system's audio backend